# Excel Index based on a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

I have the following data which I want to index in the other table base on a range

[image]

what I'm trying to achieve is that if for example Samsung had 2500 in sales the discount would 2% which is lower than 3000 and higher than 1000

I know it can be done with index,match with multiple arrays and then specifying the area or I can use if formula but I'm looking for an alternative solution

I was thinking of something like this but it seems to fail every time i try it

```
{=index(B:B,match(E2&f2,concatnate(E2,A1:A21),1)}
```

as it will match with the whats under `Samsung` in `column A`

basically what I want to do is if `column E = Samsung` find Samsung then match the sale with the numbers under Samsung only (stop matching when the cell in `column A` is not a number)

Answer (score 2):

So what I think you are looking for could be:

[image]

Formula in `G2`:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F2,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+6),1)+MATCH(E2,A:A,0)-1)
```

This takes away array entered formulas, however if you are looking for an alternative way, I would say maybe look into re-arranging your data with column like Brand/Sale/Discount as a lookup table. Much easier to work with.

If your range can increase without an equal amount of Sale possibilities between the brands I think you need an array formula nontheless, possible one like:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F2,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)):INDEX(A:A,MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)+1):INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)+1)),0)+MATCH(E2,A:A,0)),1)+MATCH(E2,A:A,)-1)
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: this is very lovely! thank you, i know it would be much easier if i rearrange the data but i don't believe it would be much of a benefit for me as in knowledge of how to tackle such problems.

Comment: but i believe if we add more parameters (sales value in column A) this formula would stop working

Comment: @ThaerJ, yes it would stop working, It wasn't clear from your question if this was possible. Either way, I updated the answer with an array formula.